# How do I use command prompt to identify derivative generation drop off?

Tags: pdf, command-line, tiff

I have one folder of approximately 7500 pdfs and a second folder with approximately 7300 tiff derivatives. Somewhere over the past 4 days of processing, intermittent tiff derivative generation failure occurred. How do I identify which files dropped off?

So far Ive tried:

diff -rq folder_pdfs folder_tiffs

However that reports all files as different given the difference in file extensions.

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I identify which files dropped off?

Use the following batch file.

**MissingFiles.cmd:**

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f %%f in ('dir /b folder_pdfs') do (
  if not exist folder_tiffs\%%~nf.tiff (
    echo folder_tiffs\%%~nf.tiff
    )
  )>>MissingFiles.txt
endlocal
```

Notes:

- `MissingFiles.txt` will contain the list of missing files.

**Example:**

```
F:\test>dir /b folder_pdfs
1.pdf
2.pdf
3.pdf
4.pdf
5.pdf

F:\test>dir /b folder_tiffs
1.tiff
3.tiff
5.tiff

F:\test>MissingFiles.cmd

F:\test>type MissingFiles.txt
folder_tiffs\2.tiff
folder_tiffs\4.tiff
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.